# Gstreamer : internal data flow error : H264 to Mjpeg to TCP

Tags: tcp, gstreamer, h.264, pipeline, mjpeg

I want to take a h264 video, decode it, re-encode it in **mjpeg** and stream it over **tcp**.

For this, I use a [raspivid](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspivid.md) video caputre which give a h264 output video piped with Gstreamer which decode, re-encode and transmit using tcp:

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -b 7000000 -fps 25 -o - | \
gst-launch-1.0 fdsrc ! video/x-h264,framerate=25/1,stream-format=byte-stream ! decodebin ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=10/1 ! \
videoconvert ! jpegenc ! tcpserversink host=192.168.24.5 port=5000 &
```

To receive I use:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.24.5 port=5000 ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

On my tcp *server* my CPU work at 90% and I have no error. We could think it's ok, but ...

On my tcp *client* I have this error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSrc:tcpclientsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2865): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTCPClientSrc:tcpclientsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

Did you have any ideas why my pipeline is broken ?

Answer (score 0):

Tried adding a videoconvert before the videosink yet?

Also, you should specify the caps for the tcp source as the second pipeline needs to know at least the framerate. I'd do something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.24.5 port=5000 ! image/jpeg, framerate=25/1 ! jpegparse ! jpegdec ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

If that still doesn't work, a GST_DEBUG=6 log from the receiving pipeline should help pinpointing the issue.